# How to put exception while scraping data off the specific tag with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python

I'm scraping the data off multiple websites. I need to scrape the list of names and heights of the players in the team. However the tag that I use seems to identify names of players AND coaches. I figured I need to maybe put an exception that signals not to scrape the names of coaches. What am I doing wrong?
Coaches names tag found under  - class="sidearm-roster-coach-name

Here's the snippet of my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster',
        'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster',
        'https://queensknights.com/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster']

df_list = list()    ##list to prevent dataframe from resetting on each iteration

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    height_swimmers = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-height") 
    first_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-first-name")
    last_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-last-name")
    
    first_name = []
    last_name = []
    height = []
```

Answer (score 1):

hello i think you need something like this I tested it and it doesn't print coach names

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster',
        'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster',
        'https://queensknights.com/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster']

df_list = list()    ##list to prevent dataframe from resetting on each iteration

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    player_full_names_container = soup.find_all('div', class_="sidearm-roster-player-name") # container for player names
    height_swimmers = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-height") 
    player_full_names = [name.find("h3").get_text().strip() for name in player_full_names_container] # List of player Full names DONT INCLUDE COACH NAMES 
    coaches_container = soup.findAll("div", class_="sidearm-roster-coach-name") # coaches container section to check if person with given name is coach or not
    coach_names = [name.find("p").get_text().strip() for name in coaches_container] # List of Coach names
    
    for name in player_full_names:

        print(name)

    print("--------------")
```